# Query for merging two table data

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables :

`stock in`

```
Id---date---Itemname----stockInqty

1 --12/12/2014 ----testitem----12

2 --13/12/2014 ----testitem11----20
```

and `stock out`

```
Id--date--Itemname---stockOutqty

1 --12/12/2014 ----testitem----7

2 --14/12/2014 ----testitem11----15
```

I need a combined result of `testitem` record between two date period in the order of

```
date----itemname----stockInqty----stockOutqty

12/12/2014--testitem---12----7

13/12/2014--testitem---20----Nil

13/12/2014--testitem---NIL----15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `FULL JOIN` if it was not MySQL, so you should use `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN` with `UNION` :

```
SELECT t1.`date`
     , t1.itemname
     , t1.stockInqty AS stockInqty
     , t2.stockInqty AS stockOutqty
FROM tbl1 t1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.`date` = t2.`date` 
                              AND t1.itemname = t2.itemname
UNION

SELECT t2.`date`
     , t2.itemname
     , t1.stockInqty AS stockInqty
     , t2.stockInqty AS stockOutqty
FROM tbl1 t1 RIGHT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.`date` = t2.`date` 
                               AND t1.itemname = t2.itemname
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...How can we make the record in the order of date (Now its orderd on the basis of first table "tbl1").

Comment: @John Mathew : You can select from the temporary table above and then `ORDER BY` date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM StockA
LEFT OUTER JOIN StockB
ON StockA.dataItem = StockB.dataItem
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM StockB
LEFT OUTER JOIN StockA
ON StockA.dataItem = StockB.dataItem
```

You must use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` operation

In MySql `FULL OUTER JOIN` can emulate with two `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in `UNION`